# Why is every instance in P also in NP [verifier-based definition]?

Tags: complexity-theory, computation-theory, np

Somewhat related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574796/np-verifier-based-definition?rq=1) question.

The verifier-based definition of NP complexity class says:

> **NP** is the class of languages which are accepted by a deterministic Turing Machine verifier in polynomial time.

All problems in **P** are considered to be in **NP**. As explanation, the following is commonly stated:

> Given a certificate for a problem in **P**, we can *ignore the certificate* and just solve the problem in polynomial time.

A verifier needs to **use** the certificate and show that the problem can be verified in polynomial time. Why does everyone keep saying *ignore the certificate and just solve the problem* ? Is solving the problem equivalent to providing a certificate ?

Comment: "A verifier needs to **use** the certificate" where did you get that idea from?

Comment: @DavidRobinson : How else would the verifier do its job without using the certificate ?

Comment: See my answer: you're taking the term "verifier" too literally. The "job" of the verifier is to give a "yes" or "no" answer to the original problem, exactly the same as any algorithm.

Comment: I can always use as the certificate "the answer is yes". For problems in P, that certificate can be verified in polynomial time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In worrying about whether the verifier "uses" the certificate, you're taking the term "verifier" too literally. A verifier is an algorithm that takes the original problem and some additional information ("a certificate"), and provides the correct answer ("yes" or "no") in polynomial time. We call it a verifier, but that doesn't impute upon it a new "job".

For problems like [subset sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), the certificate serves as a *useful shortcut*- we're given a subset that we just have to check a) adds up to 0 and b) is a subset. But if we already know the problem can be solved in polynomial time, that shortcut becomes unnecessary.

Comment: From Sipser's book : A verifier for a language `A` is an algorithm `V` where A = {w | V accepts <w,c> for some string c}. `A` is polynomially verifiable if `V` runs in polynomial time. Therefore, as long as it accepts the input (but not necessarily use all of it) in poly-time, it can be called a verifier. But, why then, does Sipser say: `A verifier uses additional information, represented by the symbol c to verify that a string w is a member of A` ? Is this me reading too much into it ?

Comment: @curryage: Indeed, it's reading too much into the word "use." Even mathematicians don't go through their books replacing "use" with "can use."